# Ruby On Rails: Can't load jquery script in blog post

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a script called jquery.social.js that loads just fine on a regular/non-database page... but doesn't load at all on a blog post.

I know the script itelf is running in the header because if I change its name in the application.js file then the page gives me an error saying the script can't be found.

So right now I have:

```
//= require jquery.socialist
```

In the application.js and the file is in my scripts folder.

The css file is in the stylesheets folder.

So I'm thinking perhaps the problem is with my link href.

I've tried it this way as well:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mypage.com/js/socialist/jquery.socialist.js">    </script>

        <link href="http://mypage.com/js/socialist/jquery.socialist.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and this way (with the script in the javascripts directory instead):

```
<link href="assets/jquery.socialist.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

And the script just doesn't seem to be running at all (there is usually a swirly thing.)

Here is the div code:

```
<div id="socialist" style="align:center; clear:both;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$('#socialist').socialist({
networks: [
{name:'facebook',id:'avividyouth'},
],
isotope:true,
random:true,
fields:['source','heading','text','date','image','followers','likes']
});
});
</script></div>
```

It just doesn't make sense that it wouldn't load...

I even tried putting the css in the stylesheets directory. I've tried having everything in the javascripts directory. (because the script loads a couple of images as well.)

Nothing seems to work. (on my other site all the scripts files are located in one js subdirectory.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Could be helpfull to know what System/CMS your Blog is build with.

For example in Joomla the link to a script should look like this:

```
<script src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If you have put your script into a subdir of the template itself.

Furthermore you have to beware that your jQuery sript actually loads befor your custom script.

Comment: It's built using the rails built-in blog generator.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using at least rails 3.1 place you stylesheet in the Assets -> Stylesheets directory and the javascript file in Assets -> Javascripts directory. Also make sure you require those files in the both of the application.js and application.css files. Either by

`//= require jquery.socialist`

or

`require_tree .`

Comment: Maybe I'm not being clear... I already have //=require jquery.socialist in the application.js and the stylesheet is already in the stylesheet folder. What I meant above is that I've tried it both ways (having it there and getting the files remotely). It works in the regular localhost:3000 but it doesn't work in localhost:3000/posts